# Jupyter Notebook creates new line instead of running block

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I recently downloaded Jupyter Notebook to run some simple python code but whenever I try to run it by pressing shift and enter, all it does is give me a new line. I tried to run

```
import sys

import tensorflow.keras
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
import tensorflow as tf
import platform

print(f"Python Platform: {platform.platform()}")
print(f"Tensor Flow Version: {tf.__version__}")
print(f"Keras Version: {tensorflow.keras.__version__}")
print()
print(f"Python {sys.version}")
print(f"Pandas {pd.__version__}")
print(f"Scikit-Learn {sk.__version__}")
gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0
print("GPU is", "available" if gpu else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

into a notebook, but it doesn't work. I also tried to run it on vs code but when I do, the terminal says...

```
   import tensorflow.keras
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Please help! I have no clue what I am supposed to do!

Comment: You can use `pip` to install modules that you don't currently have on your system, via either `pip install tensorflow` or `python -m pip install tensorflow`.

Comment: I keep getting the same error. When I ran that command in terminal, it said all the requirements were already satisfied. Is there anything else I can do? I am on MacOS if that gives more info.

Comment: Are you running your code using the same version of Python as you use to install TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

If you install "tensorflow" in Jupyter Notebook

I will NOT be installed in python environment.

If you want to run it in vscode. You ought to install "tensorflow" with pip in the python environment.

Just open the "cmd" (not the one in Jupyter) and use pip to install

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Comment: Hello. I  ran the prompt and it said everything was already satisfied. I tried to test if it worked but I am getting the same error.

Comment: @shunyi sui, in modern Jupyter there are magic commands that allow you to do installs from inside notebooks in most situations. These magic commands insure the installations occur in the environment that is the source for the kernel backing the notebooks. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic commands `%pip install` and `%conda install` for use inside notebooks. (The conda variant is for users of Anaconda/conda/mamba as the primary package manager.)

Comment: @Wayne That's right, But to avoid using conda, it is best to install it outside

Comment: @JosephChoi Can you show me the error?

Comment: @JosephChoi may you show me where you install it and where you run the code? There could be many reason and i can't tell which is if you don't show me